# How can I adjust an image's position on java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, bufferedimage

I am trying to adjust an image's position on the pop-up java window, but couldn't figure out how (I am using Buffered Image and JLabel to add it to the pop-up window).

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class CustomPanel extends JPanel
{
  private JButton EyeToggle;
  private JLabel label;

  public CustomPanel()
  {
    super();
    EyeToggle = new JButton("Toggle Eyes");
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("/Users/toprakbirben/Desktop/body.png");
    label = new JLabel(icon);
    setupPanel();
  }

  private void setupPanel()
  {
    this.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    this.add(EyeToggle);
    this.add(label);

  }

}
```

I used JFrame to create a frame for my project

```
public class Outline extends JFrame {

private CustomPanel appPanel;
  
  public Outline()
  {
    super();
    appPanel = new CustomPanel();
    setupFrame();
  }

  private void setupFrame()
  {
    this.setContentPane(appPanel);
    this.setSize(800,800);
    this.setTitle("Potato Project");
    this.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: `adjust an image's position` in what way? Where do you want to move it? Try to describe it in words or, if possible, [edit] and add an image of how it looks vs how you want it to look.

Comment: What position are your trying to get from what other position?

Comment: Hint: Use a [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) that does what you need, or use an [absolute position](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setLocation-int-int-) with no layout manager `label.setLocation(...);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: Swing: Set position of JButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478021/java-swing-set-position-of-jbutton)

Comment: @MDK https://prnt.sc/vbmqpv

Comment: @Toprak That looks like a good use case for a [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)